# HQL: Data from multiple entities with Many to Many relationship

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I have 3 entities with Many to many relationship. For example `Class`, `Student` and `Subject`.

 There are two relationship tables/entities `ClassStudent` and `StudentSubject`. There tables take care of the relationship. `ClassStudent` class looks something like this:

```
public class ClassStudent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Long classId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Long studentId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "classId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Class class

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "studentId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Student student;
}
```

`StudentSubject` class is also on the same pattern.

I am trying to write a query which each Class, it's Students and every Student's Subjects.
 Something Like

```
[
 {
  "class":{
     "id":1,
     "name":Maths
   },
   "studentDetails":[ {
      "Student":{
        "id":1
        "name":"First Name"
       },
       "Subjects": [{
          {
            "id":1,
            "code":xxx
          },
          {
           "id":2,
           "code":yy
          }
       }]
   }]
```

I tried writing a basic query but it did not work at all.

```
SELECT c, cs.student, ss.subject FROM ClassStudent cs, Class c, Student s, StudentSubject ss, Subject subject"
            + " LEFT JOIN cs.student student"
            + " LEFT JOIN ss.subject subject"
```